# mobx, render when a property value changes

Tags: react-native, mobx

I'm just getting started with Mobx in a react-native project and am having trouble understanding how to perform changes on a observed object.

Changing the object reference via the `setWorkingObject` action function in my store properly renders the UI, however if I just want to change a single property within this object, how do I cause a render?

My "store":

```
export default class MyStore {
    constructor() {
        extendObservable(this, {    
            workingObject: null
        });
    }
}
```

My "container":

```
class Container extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={new MyStore()}>
                <App />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

and my "component", which uses a simple custom input component (think of it like Checkbox) to perform changes to a property of my workingObject

```
class MyClass extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        const {store} = this.props;
        return
            <View>
                ...
                <RadioGroup
                    options={[
                        { title: "One", value: 1 },
                        { title: "Two", value: 2 }
                    ]}
                    onPress={option => {
                        store.workingObject.numberProperty = option.value;
                    }}
                    selectedValue={store.workingObject.numberProperty}
                />
            ...
            </View>
    }
}
export default inject("store")(observer(MyClass));
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't work, in fact it looks very similar to the approach used in [this example](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-reactive2015-demo/blob/master/src/components/sidebar.js)

Any other tips/critique on how I've implemented mobx welcome

Comment: as a workaround, this works: `store.workingObject= { ...store.workingObject, numberProperty: option.value };` - however, I'm sure that's not "the way".

Comment: The [**documentation**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observable.html) states that: `Only initially existing properties on an object will be made observable, although new ones can be added using extendObservable.`. It will work as intended if you change to `extendObservable(this, { workingObject: { numberProperty: null } });` in your `MyStore` constructor.

Comment: yes, i figured this out last night after reading an old closed issue. a bit hard to understand when glossed over in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that only existing properties are made observable at the time the `workingObject` is first assigned.

The solution is to declare future properties at the time of assignment, ie:

```
// some time prior to render
store.workingObject = { numberProperty:undefined };
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want to set initial value to null. Second, adding properties to observable object after it was created will not make added properties observable. You need to use `extendObservable()` instead of assigning new properties directly to observable object. Another solution is to use observable map instead.

in your store:

```
extendObservable(this, {    
    workingObject: {}
});
```

in your component:

`extendObservable(store.workingObject, {numberProperty: option.value});`

I recommend using Map in this case:

`extendObservable(this, {workingObject: new Map()});`

in your component:

`store.workingObject.set(numberProperty, option.value);`